# How to call server-side APIs with Vite in one project?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, vite, server-side-rendering

In my app with React and Vite I would like to make server-side calls for security reasons and not have them show up in the browser.
Ideally, you should not create a separate server, but make the calls in the Build phase of the project.

Is this possible? I saw that there are plugins but I would like to know if I could do everything without external plugins.
What are the steps to accomplish this and what would I need?

Is it recommended to have a node server with separate express or in this case I could do without it?
It would only be a matter of a few APIs to be called

Comment: That's not common practice and there's no need to do something like that. You can always try something like Next.js as a fullstack react framework